# Lure module bug?

Tags: pokemon-go

Anyone else had a bug to where Pokemon doesn't show up inside lure modules but show up everywhere else? My game works perfectly fine on everything but this. My friends around me, when we are all around Lure Modules, they'll have Pokemon show up left and right, and I never have any on my screen show up.

Comment: Does this happen often? Or just once/twice?

Answer (score 2):

My wife had this same problem occur and fixed it by making sure that your device time was set correctly.

In her case, her device time was 4 minutes fast and not set to use network time.

Comment: Java devil, when I get out there tomorrow I'm going to give that a try. Because yes, my phone was also set 4 minutes faster than all my friends phones, hopefully this works, thanks for the comment!